# OpenCV 3, Error when run the project with fontQt?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1

When I compile the project no errors, but when i run the project i have a problem with fontQt.

OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is compiled without QT support) in fontQt, file /home/developer/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 507
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/developer/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:507: error: (-213) The library is compiled without QT support in function fontQt

Aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void pushButtonCallBack(int, void *font);

Mat originImg, tmpImg;
string win_img = "win_img";
char msg[50];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
std::cout << "OpenCV add text to img..." << std::endl;

originImg = imread(argv[1],IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

if(originImg.empty())
{
    cout << "url is not true" << endl;
    return -1;
}

string AddText = "AddText";
string text= "Text";

cv::QtFont font = fontQt("Arail", 20, Scalar(255,0,0,0), QT_FONT_BLACK, QT_STYLE_NORMAL);

createButton(AddText, pushButtonCallBack, &font, QT_PUSH_BUTTON );

imshow(win_img,originImg);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

```
void pushButtonCallBack(int, void *font)
{
addText(originImg, "Click", Point(50,50), *(QtFont *)font);
imshow(win_img, originImg);
return;
}
```

this is my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(lesson_3_3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(lesson_3_3 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries( lesson_3_3 ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: _"The library is compiled without QT support"_ seems quite clear. Have you compiled OpenCV with Qt support? Any reason you can't use standard fonts, so you don't need to recompile OpenCV?

Comment: How I understand , if I add Qt to cmake it's will be work.

Comment: Hi @NafeKzir, how to add Qt to cmake?